# validar si un string o int se encuentra vació c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

quería hacer una pregunta un poco novata, es que estoy haciendo un programa básico de c++ y no es como java o c#, lo que busco es simplemente verificar si un string se encuentra vacío, si es así, quiero que la pregunta se siga repitiendo.

```
        cout<<"Ingrese su nombre:"<<endl;
        cin>>nombre;
```

también me gustaría saber cómo podría hacerlo con un int

```
        cout<<"Ingrese su edad:"<<endl;
        cin>>edad;
```

también sino les molesta me gustaría saber cómo podría hacer si quisiera saber si un vector de string se encuentra vacío, en la posición donde espero algún dato

```
        cout<<"Ingrese su nombre:"<<endl;
        cin>>datosPersonales[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saber si un `std::string` está vacío, basta con usar la [función `empty`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty):

```
std::string s;

if (s.empty())
    std::cout << "Está vacío\n";
```

En cambio, no existe el concepto de un "*`int` vacío*".

---

Por lo que veo en tu pregunta, no quieres saber si una cadena o un entero están "*vacíos*", en realidad quieres saber si pudiste leer una cadena o un entero.

Para saberlo basta con comprobar el estado del flujo de datos tras la lectura, si su estado no es correcto es que no se leyó correctamente:

```
int main()
{
    std::string nombre;
    if (std::cin >> nombre)
        std::cout << "Se leyó " << nombre << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "No se pudo leer la cadena\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Esto también funciona con números:

```
int main()
{
    int numero;
    if (std::cin >> numero)
        std::cout << "Se leyó " << numero << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "No se pudo leer el número\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Cuando el flujo de lectura se queda en un estado inválido, permanece en este estado hasta que lo "*limpies*", así que tras una lectura incorrecta debes llamar a [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear):

```
int main()
{
    std::string nombre;
    if (std::cin >> nombre)
        std::cout << "Se leyó " << nombre << '\n';
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No se pudo leer la cadena\n";
        std::cin.clear();
    }

    int numero;
    if (std::cin >> numero)
        std::cout << "Se leyó " << numero << '\n';
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No se pudo leer el número\n";
        std::cin.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: vieras que soy nueva en c++ y si vi esta funcion .empty(), pero nose como usarla porque en codeblock me marca error, se ocupa importar alguna librería ?

Comment: @Esther qué error obtienes al usar `empty`? Esa función forma parte del estándar al menos desde C++11. Si no estás usando esa o una versión superior no la encontrarás. Simplemente necesitamos poder reproducir el problema para ayudarte.

Comment: @EstherPorta para usar la función `string::empty` basta con incluir `#include <string>`. ¿Qué error ves exáctamente?